# Why is hunger is not depleting on my server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have the server set to easy difficulty and am on survival mode, yet hunger doesn't stay depleted. When I try jumping around and running, the bar goes down one but then instantly regenerates. If anyone can tell me why this is happening and how I can fix it, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What kind of server is it? Vanilla? Bukkit?

Comment: It's a Vanilla server.

Comment: I'm sorry this is a stupid question, but what does the `difficulty` configuration in the server config file says? What number does it say in `difficulty=<number>`?

Comment: The difficulty number is set to 1.

Comment: Okey. I'm just thinking if the config is 0. Apparently it's not the case.

Comment: Have you been using command blocks on the server? When you open your inventory, do you see any potion effects active? Try copying the world file into a single-player world and playing it for a while, to see if it's the server config or the world file itself causing this issue.

Comment: Alright, I think I fixed the problem. I copied a new server config file over the old one and that seems to have worked. Hunger is depleting like normal. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

What may be happening is you are in a special area around spawn.

Many servers have an area around spawn where you cannot take damage or lose hunger. This is so new players to the server can explore spawn without the  risk of killing themselves before they have even started.

Try moving out of the spawn area. You will generally be able to tell this as there may be markers on the terrain, or a message will appear in chat.

However, if this is your own server, I suggest you make sure it is not set to peaceful difficulty. In peaceful difficulty, your health regenerates instantly and you regenerate health quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If your random tick speed is higher than the normal(3) it was tend to cause that to happen. You can change it back to normal by `/gamerule randomTickSpeed 3`